SQL query returns null, but should return a value
I have this query - the data stored in column amount is of type decimal(12,2), and sum2/expenses is a negative value, the other two are positive values.
SELECT 
    sum1 + sum2 - sum3
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum1 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'income') x 
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum2 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'expense') y 
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum3 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'transfer') z;

It returns NULL, if just one of the sub queries returns NULL, even though one or two returns a value.
How can I make the calculation work even though I get NULL from one, two or all of the sub queries?
I tried to add .. WHERE amount IS NOT NULL .. Like so:
SELECT 
    sum1 + sum2 - sum3
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum1 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         amount IS NOT NULL 
         AND MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '2' AND type = 'income') x 
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum2 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         amount IS NOT NULL 
         AND MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '2' AND type = 'expense') y 
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) AS sum3 
     FROM 
         economy_transactions 
     WHERE 
         amount IS NOT NULL 
         AND MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' 
         AND account_source = '2' AND type = 'transfer') z;

But there was no difference. I still get the same results as without.
Before I came up with the query above, I did this, which works fine, but I have to do the calculations afterwards with PHP.
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM economy_transactions WHERE MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'income'
UNION
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM economy_transactions WHERE MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'expense'
UNION
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM economy_transactions WHERE MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024' AND account_source = '1' AND type = 'transfer';

Any advice is appreciated.

Side note: use the appropriate type - even in your WHERE clause; both MONTH() and YEAR() return values of type INT - so why are you checking against string values here??? AND MONTH(date) = '7' AND YEAR(date) = '2024'  - use the proper INT datatype and just do AND MONTH(date) = 7 AND YEAR(date) = 2024 - otherwise you get unnecessary and wasteful implicit conversions in all your queries ....

Thank you for the info. To be honest, I was not aware there was a difference. I'm pretty much just going by trial and error, and both worked, so i didn't think much of it.

If you add or subtract NULL to a value the result itself will be NULL. In your expression you need to convert any null value to zero to prevent that from happening. For example in SQL Server:
SELECT ISNULL(sum1, 0) + ISNULL(sum2, 0) - ISNULL(sum3, 0)

For MySQL use IFNULL and if using Oracle use NVL.

No need to use different functions depending on the RDBMS, simply use COALESCE which works on each.

Ah, so simple.
I ended up using SELECT COALESCE(sum(sum1), 0) + COALESCE(sum(sum2), 0) - COALESCE(sum(sum3), 0)
Works like a charm
Thank you for help and explanation.
